# WebClient Spring Boot : Data is saved only if it returns value

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webclient

I am using Mailchimp api when I return value it works fine but when I don't return any value it does not work and also not throwing any exception.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/members/add/{email}") //using GET to test
public Mono<String> addMember(@PathVariable String email) {
    User user = new User();
    user.setFirst_name("Test");
    user.setLast_name("Data");
    user.setEmail_id(email);
    return mailchimpService.create(user);
}
```

This is not saving data

```
@GetMapping(value = "/members/add/{email}") //using GET to test
    public Mono<String> addMember(@PathVariable String email) {
        User user = new User();
        user.setFirst_name("Test");
        user.setLast_name("Data");
        user.setPhone("");
        user.setEmail_id(email);
        mailchimpService.create(user);

        return null;
    }

public Mono<String> create(User user) {
        try {
            Members members = convertUserToMailchimpObject(user);
            return webClient.post()
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(members))
                    .exchangeToMono(clientResponse -> {
                        if (clientResponse.statusCode().is5xxServerError()) {
                            clientResponse.body((clientHttpResponse, context) -> clientHttpResponse.getBody());
                            System.out.println(clientResponse.statusCode() + " statusCode error");
                            System.out.println(clientResponse.statusCode().value() + " value error");
                            return clientResponse.bodyToMono(String.class);
                        } else
                            System.out.println(clientResponse.statusCode() + " statusCode");
                        System.out.println(clientResponse.statusCode().value() + " value");
                        return clientResponse.bodyToMono(String.class);
                    });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that in reactive programming nothing happens until you subscribe. The create method is never get subscribed thus the webclient call is never made.

The first snippet works because the Webflux framework will subscribe for you as long as you provide your publisher(a Mono).